# Errors manipulating array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object

I want to build an array of objects that can be removed and added.

So first of all I have initialised the array in the .h file like this:

```
@property (strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *addArray;
```

Then in the .m file I initialise the array if it is empty like this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.addArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"likesArray"];

if ([self.addArray count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"array is empty");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.addArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [defaults objectForKey:@"likesArray"]];

}
```

I then try and add and remove objects which will look like this:

```
@{@"name":_name,@"genre":_genre,@"info":_info}
```

By doing this to add an object:

```
[self.addArray addObject:@{@"name":_name,@"genre":_genre,@"info":_info}];
```

And doing this to remove an object

```
[self.addArray removeObject:@{@"name":_name,@"genre":_genre,@"info":_info}];
```

And finally I store the array like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.addArray forKey:@"likesArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

But I am receiving error messages like this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `mutableCopy` here:

```
self.addArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"likesArray"] mutableCopy];
```

as user defaults will have returned an `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`.

Also this code is better:

```
if (!self.addArray) {
    self.addArray = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```

Comment: @Maximilian See my recent edit; I don't like the "empty test" you use in your code.